# Number of possible subsets with specified minimum size and maximum overlap.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given $n > 1, 1 \leq k < n$ and  $1 \leq m < k$, compute the size of a set-system $\mathcal{H}$, that is defined over a universe of $n$ elements and satisfies the following properties.

1. $\forall H \in \mathcal{H}$, it holds that: $|H| \geq k$.
2. $\forall G, H \in \mathcal{H}$, where $G \neq H$, it holds that: $|H \cap G| \leq m$.

PS: I want to thank @Ross Millikan and @bof. Their comments have helped me to better understand and state the problem.

Comment: Is $m$ an arbitrary value (less than $n/k$), or is it a function of $n$?

Comment: It's just an arbitrary value, such that, $1 \leq m \leq n/k - 1$.

Comment: Where you wrote $\forall G\subset S$ did you really mean $\forall G\subset S$ or did you mean "for every set $G$ ***in the family***"?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are trying to say: "Let $S$ be an $n$-element set; how big can a family $\mathcal H$ of subsets of $S$ be, if (1) $|H|\ge n/k$ for each $H\in\mathcal H$, and (2) $|G\cap H|\le m$ whenever $G,H\in\mathcal H$ and $G\ne H$?" Is that your question? If so, you're asking about the much-studied set packing problem. Of course there is no loss of generality is supposing that $|H|=n/k$ for all $H\in\mathcal H$.

Comment: By the way, the trivial upper bound is $$|\mathcal H|\le\binom n{m+1}$$ since each $(m+1)$-element subset of $S$ is contained in at most one element of $\mathcal H$.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of the set packing problem. I will read about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As written, you can consider $G$ to be $S$ as that will be the tightest constraint. Then $H$ has to have between $\frac nk$ and $m-1$ elements inclusive. Maybe you meant to find a family of subsets such that any pair has small intersection.

Comment: $G$ is a proper subset of $S$ and $m < n/k$. So, I'm not sure what you mean by $H$ having between $n/k$ and $m-1$ elements. I think you meant to say that $H$ has $n/k$ to $n-1$ elements from $S$. I'm looking for a closed-form expression for the number of (proper) subsets that satisfy the given constraints, i.e., some kind of bound on the size of the family of subsets of $S$, such that, the size of each member is at least $n/k$ and their pairwise intersection is at most $m$.

Comment: But $G$ could be the same as $H$, in which case the intersection is all of $H$ and $H$ has to have $m-1$ or less elements.  You said for all $G$, so we pick the worst case for any given $H$.

Comment: You're correct! The question was not well worded by me. Apologies for that. I have updated it now. Thanks!